# Error connecting with SSL

Tags: delphi, ssl, get, indy

I'm trying to connecto to this url, just using a get request.
[Goberment page](https://loginc.mat.sat.gob.mx/nidp/app/login?id=XACCertiSAT&sid=0&option=credential&sid=0)
But always get the error EIdOSSLConnectError "Error connecting with SSL"

The code I use, is this, it works with other pages, but not this one

```
IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := true;
IdHTTP1.AllowCookies := true;
IdHTTP1.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket.Create(IdHTTP1);
IdHTTP1.CookieManager := TIdCookieManager.Create(IdHTTP1);
with TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket(IdHTTP1.IOHandler) do begin
  SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
  SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
  SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
  SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
  PassThrough := True;
end;
IdHttp1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0';
IdHTTP1.RedirectMaximum := 30;
sHtml := IdHTTP1.Get('https://loginc.mat.sat.gob.mx/nidp/app/login?id=XACCertiSAT&sid=0&option=credential&sid=0');//<----Error here
```

Delphi 7, Indy 9.00.10

Thanks for any advice

Comment: You are using an extremely old version of Indy 9 (the last version was 9.0.50).  Indy 9 requires customized (and old) OpenSSL DLLs, it does not support modern OpenSSL versions. Please upgrade to Indy 10 and use the latest official OpenSSL 1.0.2 DLLs, which you can get from Indy's [Fulgan mirror](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/).

Comment: Your `RedirectMaximum` value seems to expect redirects almost across the whole Universe (42 is the maximum the Universe accepts :)

Comment: I did update to 10.6.2.0, now I get this error: "Error connecting with SSL error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure"

Comment: Thanks Remy Lebeau, with the update did it work, the problems was, as Bob3411 mentioned, the `SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;` changed to `SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;` and also using the openssl dll openssl-1.0.2-i386-win32.zip, openssl-1.0.2-x64_86-win64.zip  didn't work. Victoria, I use 30 redirects, because, I did not know how many times would do it :p. Off topic, Remy, have you installed reportmanager 2_7 with indy 10? thanks guys

Comment: Dont use the `SSLOptions.Method` property directly (it is deprecated, so pretend it doesn't exist), use the `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` property instead.  If you enable multiple versions (like `[sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2]`), the `Method` will be set to `sslvSSLv23` for you (but that is an implementation detail).  Setting `Method` to `sslvSSLv23` is the same as setting `SSLVersions` to `[sslvSSLv2,sslvSSLv3,sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2]`.

Comment: I got it, I will change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that site wants TLS v1.2, since that is what gets negotiated when I go there with a browser.

Also, if in my PaleMoon browser I next go to about:config and set the pref named security.tls.version.max to 1, I revisit your url then wit TLS v1.0 and I get:
Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to loginc.mat.sat.gob.mx.
Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s). 
(Error code: ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)

However, other sites I tried (such as banks) still work okay with TLS v1 set that way. It seems your target site is finicky, so I'd try adjusting your line:
    SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;

Comment: and this site says:  Your client is using TLS 1.0, which is very old, possibly susceptible to the BEAST attack, and doesn't have the best cipher suites available on it. Additions like AES-GCM, and SHA256 to replace MD5-SHA-1 are unavailable to a TLS 1.0 client as well as many more modern cipher suites.   https://www.howsmyssl.com/